# Can this equation always be true? $|\cos(\ln x)-2\sin(\ln x)| \le |\cos(\ln x)|-|2\sin(\ln x)|$

Tags: absolute-value

$$|\cos(\ln x)-2\sin(\ln x)| \le |\cos(\ln x)|-|2\sin(\ln x)|$$

I'm confusing with $$|x-y|\ge||x|-|y||$$

because if I put minus in to $\sin(\ln x)$

It would be
$$|\cos(\ln x)+2\sin(-\ln x)|\le|\cos(\ln x)|+|2\sin(-\ln x)|$$

Then it end up with $$|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is not true.

Let $\tan y=-\frac 1 2$. Then, $\cos y=-2 \sin y$. If $x=e^{y}$ the RHS is $0$ but LHS is not.